# TypeError: Cannot read property 'useContext' of null nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, apollo, strapi

I am going to get user from context and use it in header in nextjs strapi apollo graphql project User is accessable in App function but outside its giving above error. Is context values accessable outside function if yes how can I access it if no how to structure it so that I can use it in request header.

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import { Provider } from "../context/AppContext";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import withApollo from "next-with-apollo";
import { BACKEND_URL } from "../helpers";
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { AppContext } from "../context/AppContext";
import { ApolloClient, ApolloProvider, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";



const { user } = useContext(AppContext);

console.log("user from context in _app", user);

function App({ Component, pageProps, apollo }) {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <ApolloProvider client={apollo}>
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default withApollo(({ initialState, headers }) => {
  return new ApolloClient({
    uri: `${BACKEND_URL}/graphql`,
    cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState || {}),
    ...(user && {
      headers: {
        authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`,
      },
    }),
  });
})(App);
```

Comment: You cannot `hooks` outside react component.

Answer (score 1):

On my machine, Next.js didn't work if, in Windows Terminal, the disk letter (for example, `C:`) of the "current directory" was written in lowercase (as `c:` in this example).

After I changed the current directory from `c:\dev\project` to `C:\dev\project`, the error went away.

Source: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7626#issuecomment-541430221

Comment: This worked for me and also applies to caps in the file path too (Linux), I lost hours over this and when I saw your comment I remembered this had happened to me a few years back.